# How to call ic_action_overflow button(option menu )onclicklistner in oncreate of main class in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

i need to call Onclicklistner to ic_action_overflow button(option menu button) in oncreate of main class ....how to write onclicklistner to  that button..thanks in advance!

code should look like...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {    

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ic_action_overflow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //  TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //body
        }
    });
 }
 }
```

Comment: are you using toolbar?

Answer (score 1):

use performClick method

```
ic_action_overflow.performClick();
```

Comment: how to call default ic_action_overflow of android..because its showing "can not resolve ic_action_overflow"

Answer (score 1):

why you aren't using

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.ic_action_overflow){
        //your code 
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

in your activity ?

Answer (score 1):

```
   @Override
   public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
switch (keyCode) {

case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:
    // Do Sometihng
    break;

default:
    break;
}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
   }
```

You need do it like this

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you define this attribute in menu.xml in menu folder inside res

```
<item android:id="@+id/ic_action_overflow"
 android:title="ic_action_overflow"/>
```

then in your MainActivity call onCreateOptionsmenu to display if you already haven't.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Now, Finally click listener for the ic_action_overflow

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.ic_action_overflow:
           //Do work here
           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Click Successful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
}
return true;
}
```

Hope this helped  you!!